# build ant project android error

Tags: java, android, ant, build

when i try to launch build ant i have this error:

```
[javac] Compiling 12 source files to C:\Users\brahim\Android\****\*****_Presentation\bin\classes
[javac] C:\Users\brahim\Android\*****\****_Presentation\src\com\***\****\activity\AbstractActivity.java:29: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[javac]     List<AbstractFragment> mHistoryNav = new ArrayList<>();
[javac]                                                        ^
[javac]   (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
[javac] 1 error

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\brahim\Android\*****\****_Presentation\custom_rules.xml:47: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\brahim\Android\****\****_Presentation\custom_rules.xml:62: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

line 47 and  62 of my custom_rules are:

```
  <target name="-compile" depends="-pre-build, -build-setup, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
    <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
        <!-- merge the project's own classpath and the tested project's classpath -->
        <path id="project.javac.classpath">
            <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
            <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
            <path path="${java.compiler.classpath}" />
            <fileset dir="compile-libs" includes="*.jar"/>
        </path>
        <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
                debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
                destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
                verbose="${verbose}"
                classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
                fork="${need.javac.fork}">
```

Anyone knows why i get this error ?

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Edit:

${java.source} = 1.5 when i hardcoded it yo ="1.7"
and also hardcoded ${java.target} = 1.7

the problem is gone, why eclipse ant take version 1.5 by default?

Comment: What is the value of `${java.source}`?

Comment: = 1.5 , how can i change it?  it's strange because, my java compiler is set to sdk 1.7

Comment: Try to add it hardcoded  source="1.7"

Comment: i got this error

   [javac] Compiling 12 source files to C:\Users\brahim\Android\****\****_Presentation\bin\classes
    [javac] javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7

Comment: Can you add it as to your question as Update please. Can you also echoing `JAVA_HOME`?

Comment: java -version on cmd give me     java version "1.7.0.75"

Comment: Also set target to 1.7

Comment: What target on eclipe ? when i can find it ?

Comment: in your build file: target="${java.target}"

Comment: problem solved when i hardcoded also target :) 

why eclipse ant take version 1.5 by default? i don't understand that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73925/discussion-between-jens-and-tamtoum1987).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `${java.source}` is lower then `1.7` or you use a JDK version lower then 1.7 to compile your app. Change it to JDK 1.7 or higher to solve your problem.

Comment: I already do that, in ant build configuration table jre i selected jdk1.7, the same in properties java compiler